# A question on Integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Consider $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1} \in l_2$ and $L(t) = 1+\epsilon t$. Let $x$ be fixed such that $0 < x < L(t)$.  Does there exist $\tau \geq 0$ such that the following inequality cound be true
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
\int_{0}^{\tau}\bigl|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n e^{-i\pi^2n^2\frac{t}{L(t)}}\sin\bigl(\frac{n\pi x}{L(t)}\bigr)\bigr|^2 dt \gtrsim \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|a_n|^2
\end{equation}

Comment: Would you want a constant independent of $x$? Then that looks extremely unlikely as the left hand side should tend to $0$ as $x\to 0$. If the constant can depend on $x$, maybe.

Comment: Yes, I need the constant depend on $x$